# Convert a matlab loop to R loop

Tags: r, matlab

I have a transition matrix as follow:

```
        stage1   stage2 stage3   stage4   stage5
stage1 0.967716 0.017084  0.000 0.000000 0.015200
stage2 0.100000 0.500000  0.200 0.100000 0.100000
stage3 0.200000 0.300000  0.300 0.100000 0.100000
stage4 0.000000 0.000000  0.038 0.917498 0.044502
stage5 0.000000 0.000000  0.000 0.000000 1.000000
```

The following matlab code is a conditional loop for the first row of this transition matrix

```
for i=1:1000
    a=unifrnd(0,1);
    if a<=0.967716 
        stage(i)=1;
    else
         if a<=0.9848
             stage(i)=2;
         else

             stage(i)=5;

         end
    end
end
```

This means that in 1000 iteration, the number generated by the uniform distribution will be assigned to one of the five-stage if the condition will be true. The generated number first compared with the probability of stay in the current state and then if the condition did not meet compared with the sum of the previous probability and the probability of transition to the next state( 0.967716 + 0.017084 ) and so on.

Now I would like to convert these codes to the R codes. So, if I have a trace matrix  "f" the number generated by the uniform distribution will be assigned to one of the elements of this matrix( columns are equal to the above transition matrix states (stages) and rows are equal to the number of iterations).

`f<-matrix(NA, nrow=5, ncol=1000)`

...

Someone can help me?

Comment: Hi Meysam, could you be a bit more precise on what you are asking. Did you already try something to solve the problem ? Is it your first R code ? If yes you could learn the basics through R for beginner of Emmanuel Paradis.

Comment: Hi Rémi Coulaud, Thanks for your response. I'm almost a beginner user of the R. Yes, previously tried to solve this problem use the following code with considering another hypothetical example. Thanks for your suggestion.p<- matrix(NA, ncol=5, nrow=50)
for(i in 1:nrow(p)){
  a<-runif(5,0,1)
  if(a<=0.25){p[,2]<-a<0.25}
  else if(a<=0.66){p[,3]<-a<0.66}
  else if(a<=0.88){p[,4]<-a<0.88}
  else{p[,5]}
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand your problem, you want to model several stages of a markovian process. Your process take five stages. In your exemples, you only want to model the probability law to pass from a stage to another one.

I took what you try and I modify it to make it work.

## Be careful :

- When you want to complete matrix, you must specify both line and column `m[i, j]` to fill the case at row `i` and column `j`.
- If you do simulation with randomness use `set.seed` for reproductibility.
- Before using a function like `runif` check how it works :
  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Uniform.html

In this example, the markovian process has no probability to stay in the same stage.

```
p <- matrix(NA, ncol=5, nrow=50)
set.seed(123) # It fixed the seed for random generation of your computer. Very useful to reproductible code.
for(i in 1:nrow(p)){
  a<-runif(1, 0, 1) # You want only one uniform random number not five
  if(a <= 0.25){
    p[i, 2] <- 2} # p has n rows and you need to allocate one row by one row, so i is needed
  else if(a<= 0.66){
    p[i, 3] <- 3}
  else if(a <= 0.88){
    p[i, 4]<- 4}
  else{
    p[i, 5] <- 5}}
```

I change a bit what you already try because you have five columns, you can just put a one in the right case. The idea is to see if you find back the probability thanks to simulation the probability law to obtain each stage. Is to say :

```
0.25 to have 2
0.41 to have 3
0.22 to have 4
0.12 to have 5
```

We obtain thanks to this code :

```
n <- 10000
p <- matrix(0, ncol=5, nrow=n)
set.seed(123)
for(i in 1:nrow(p)){
  a <- runif(1, 0, 1)
  if(a <= 0.25){
    p[i, 2] <- 1}
  else if(a<= 0.66){
    p[i, 3] <- 1}
  else if(a <= 0.88){
    p[i, 4]<- 1}
  else{
    p[i, 5] <- 1}}
```

Which gives these probabilities :

```
 colSums(p) / n
 0.0000 0.2475 0.4173 0.2211 0.1141
```

It works ! I hope it helps you.

Comment: Dear Rémi Coulaud, 
Hi,
Thank you for your help and recommendations.
That's right I want to simulate serval stages of a markovian process. But I have another question, if possible.
As you mentioned in this example the markovian process has no probability to stay in the same stage. How can this be considered in this example?

Comment: Dear Meysam, first if the answer satisfy your question you can validate it. Secondly, surely you can put a probability of staying at the same stage using another `else if` and filling  `p[i, 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `stage(6)=6;` do you mean `stage(i)=6;`?

If so, your Matlab code can easily be rewritten as

```
stage = discretize(unifrnd(0,1,1000,1),[0,0.92,0.94,0.97,1],[1,2,3,6],'IncludedEdge','right');
```

The code in R is very similar, you can find the function call here
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-4/topics/discretize

Comment: Dear friend, Thanks for your response, Yes, it’s a mistake. stage (i)=6 is correct. Thank you. The mentioned loop is part of a nested loop that I want to convert it to the R code. So, I don't think your suggested solution would be appropriate for a nested loop. In general, I would like to learn how to convert these codes into the R codes and assign the generated number from a uniform distribution (in 1000 iteration) to the rows and columns of a matrix.